# How to check if a char sequence isn't included in a group of char sequences using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite URLs which don't include specific words like 'contact', 'about', 'list' etc. (I know it would have been easier to check for the ones for which I want to do the rewriting, but it's not possible in my case).

I found how to check for a single word:

```
^(?:(?!list).)+$
```

Is there a way I can verify something like:

```
^(?:(?!list).)+$ AND ^(?:(?!contact).)+$ AND ^(?:(?!about).)+$ AND ...   ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!list|contact|about).)+$
```

would cover all these cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to match for some words in a URL, you can do this:

```
(list|contact|about)
```

If any of the words are in the url, this is `true`. Depending on you context, you can take the negative of this match, for example:

PHP: `!preg_match("/(list|contact|about)/",$url)`

mod_rewrite: `RewriteRule !(list|contact|about) /404.html`

Hope, this is what you need!